# Python: String/ List Value from Scrapping Website

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

Im trying to get a list of values from a website that is structured the following way:

```
<sellableUnits>
    <attributes> 
      <id>SIZE_1317058</id> 
      <type>size</type> 
      <value>XS</value> 
    </attributes>
```

This repeats itself for all the sizes available on the website.

Im using the following code:

```
all_sizes = []    
for variants in data['sellableUnits']:
    sizes = variants['attributes'][0]['value']
    all_sizes.append(sizes)

all_sizes = '\n'.join(all_sizes)
```

I can get all the values, however the list of values repeats each value 4 times. No idea why. What i get is this:

XS
XS
XS
XS
S
S
S
S
M
M
M
M
L
L
L
L
XL
XL
XL
XL

When i should get: XS S M L XL

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show the full xml here. It is possible there are 4 variant of each size.

Comment: It could be helpful if you can add the URL.

Comment: Its to big to share in here, but here is the direct link:

https://www.footlocker.pt/api/products/pdp/317353713630

Comment: You can simply do `all_sizes = set(all_sizes)` to get rid of duplicates. Or add condition `if sizes not in all_sizes: all_sizes.append(sizes)`

Comment: @JaSON i get this as a return: {'S', 'M', 'XL', 'L', 'XS'}, it looses the order it gets each size. How to i maintain that order? XS, S, M, L, XL

Comment: Try second suggestion

Comment: tried, returns the value repeated again: ['XS', 'XS', 'XS', 'XS', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'XL', 'XL', 'XL', 'XL']

Comment: I'm not sure you did it right. Instead of just `all_sizes.append(sizes)` use `if sizes not in all_sizes: all_sizes.append(sizes)`. This will add value to list **only** if it's not in list

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying, there are multiple elements in the `'sellableUnits'` that have those sizes.

As you can see the first 2 in the image below. So your code is doing precisely what it should be doing.

[image]

Comment: How can i change it to return only the first value per size?